# Add columns to a query

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
user_id     time_completed
    4           86.30887
    5           57.81364
    5           35.50281
    5           10.00000
    5           74.19355
    5           31.91489
    6           15.00000
    6           20.50000
```

I sum the times and replace the users from this other table (db_users):

```
id          username        country
1           admin           ES
2           peter           IT
3           tom             US
4           user            GB
5           joey            GE
6           helen           FR
```

But I also need country row also appears:

```
user_id     time_completed      country
joey           209.42489            GE
user           86.30887             GB
helen           35.50000            FR
```

Take a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d1b/11

Comment: You have the join already, just add b.country to the select statement? works fine for me in fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, add only the missing field

```
SELECT b.username, SUM(time_COmpleted) totalTime, b.country
FROM tableName a 
      INNER JOIN  db_users b
        ON (a.user_id = b.id)
GROUP BY b.username, b.country
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d1b/18)

according to your demo, all the users live on `GB`

Comment: they dont, the others just dont have time-entries

Comment: @Flo what are you talking about? even though they have different time but still they are on the same location.

Comment: In the end it doesnt matter, but if you look at the table there are users from other countries. But in the time table there are no entries for those users, which is the reason why only uk users appear in output

Answer (score 3):

You will just add that field:

```
SELECT b.username, SUM(time_COmpleted) totalTime, b.country
FROM tableName a 
      INNER JOIN  db_users b
        ON (a.user_id = b.id)
GROUP BY b.username, b.country
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d1b/18)

Answer (score 0):

Well, just add the country to the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT b.username, SUM(time_COmpleted) totalTime, b.country
FROM tableName a 
    INNER JOIN  db_users b
    ON (a.user_id = b.id)
GROUP BY b.username
```